# Can a local FS have a shared git history for multiple git repository instances of the same repository?

Tags: git

Git is pretty amazing, but if you have multiple instances of the same repository, the size used can start to add up.

Given what I understand about the internals (which I admit is limited) it would seem to me that all instances should conceptually be able to share part of a instance database, the part that houses the actual files/deltas (i.e. the history).  The stuff that states what files are being pointed at, branch information, etc, would of course have to be on a per instance level.

Not only does having entire repositories (or even a shallow one) in each instance seem to be wasteful, it is problematic on constrained systems.

Is there some current mechanism in git to do this?  If not, does it sound like it could be done?  Maybe by sharing a subdirectory of `.git` via a junction/symbolic link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, and in fact this is (partially) the default if one of the repositories is cloned from the other.

From the [`git clone` manpage](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone):

> **`--local`**
>   **`-l`**
>   When the repository to clone from is on a local machine, this flag bypasses the normal "Git aware" transport mechanism and clones the repository by making a copy of HEAD and everything under objects and refs directories. *The files under `.git/objects/` directory are hardlinked to save space when possible.*
>
> If the repository is specified as a local path (e.g., /path/to/repo), this is the default, and --local is essentially a no-op. If the repository is specified as a URL, then this flag is ignored (and we never use the local optimizations). Specifying --no-local will override the default when /path/to/repo is given, using the regular Git transport instead.

(*emphasis* added)

This means that on systems which support hardlinks (Linux and Unix systems, including Mac OS; theoretically Windows but I don’t know if Git supports them there), the Git object files will be stored only once on disc.

However, I can’t find anything saying this is still the case on `git fetch` or `git push`; it might be that only the files that existed when you first made the clone are shared this way. That’s certainly the case if you get changes between the repositories via a remote.

---

Another option is [Git worktrees](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree). This allows you to have multiple branches of a repository checked out at the same time in different directories. In that case there is only one version of the repository on disc at all, so it is always shared even when you update.

However, this doesn’t let you have the *same* branch checked out in different work trees (without the `--force` option, which is still experimental), which might be an advantage or a disadvantage depending on your use case. It also doesn’t let you have a read-only repository and a writable clone of that, which might be useful if you have more than one user on the same computer.

Depending on your use case, either option (or both together) might be what you want.

Comment: Apparently there’s another option, [`git clone -s`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#git-clone---shared), but I don’t know enough about it to say what its advantages are over the first thing I mentioned. The man page says that its disadvantage is that it’s dangerous unless you know what you’re doing, so you should read up on it more if it looks like that’s what you want.

Comment: So using `--local` the *files* are hardlinked.  This means that any new files added to one repository are not seen in the others, unless they are pushed/pulled?  How does that work against the remote?  Does one local clone become the remote to the other locals and is the one which you would push to an actual server remote?

Comment: @Adrian If you clone both from a remote server, then the `--local` part doesn’t apply. It’s only if you make one of the repositories with `git clone /path/to/other/repo` that the files are hardlinked, and the new repo’s `origin` remote will be the original local repo instead of the server. You can use it the way you suggest, or you can set up additional remotes for the other local repositories. Either way, they’d count as separate repositories and not automatically see each others’ changes. If you want them to automatically update, worktrees is the answer.

Comment: Interesting.  Would like to know about if `fetch` and `push` would result in hardlinks as wellthough.  Otherwise this would only be postponing an issue.

Comment: @Adrian Based on my experiments with Git 2.15.0, only clone uses hardlinks, not fetch.

Comment: Hmmm. Worktrees seem like a viable option. There is a `--force` parameter to have it checkout the same brach. But I assume that `Multiple checkout in general is still experimental, and the support for submodules is incomplete. It is NOT recommended to make multiple checkouts of a superproject` is referring to that, discouraging is use? Or something else?

Comment: @Adrian I read that as using multiple worktrees for the same branch isn’t necessarily going to work as you expect, and it’s *especially* bad if you use submodules. I’d just avoid doing that and use different branches for different worktrees; you shouldn’t need to have the same one checked out in multiple places.

Comment: Looks like it can be used as a full repository.  I can switch to another branch from the worktree.  Are there any potential pitfalls for doing that?  Why does the man page kinda emphasize that this is for emergencies?

Comment: @Adrian I don’t see the man page mention the ability to switch to another branch from the worktree at all (I’d expect it to work fine unless another worktree has that branch checked out), and the only time it mentions emergencies is in a particular example.

Answer (score 0):

Managing multiple working trees that share the same repository was implemented about two years ago (Git 2.6 or so). The command is [`git worktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree).